# How can i import data from text file into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I have excel file, transformed into text file (file->save as), now i want to import this file into MySQL, i heard that the `LOAD DATA INFILE` could do this very quickly, however i don't know how to use it, should i write a php script in which i put the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax?

Answer (score 5):

I guess your data is in CSV if you exported it from Excel? Then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Explanation:

Fields terminated is your CSV seperator, enclosed by denotes that strings are enclosed with double quotes and line terminated by is the indicator for LOAD DATA INFILE to insert another row. 
The last line is to ignore the header.

Comment: How can it be in CSV if i have to write `data.txt`? and where should i put that script? in a php file?

Comment: data.txt is your filename. It can be yourdata.csv, whatever.omg, etc. Only thing that matters is that its textdata. You can run the query in your `mysql` console, import the csv per phpMyAdmin, run it from a php file with `mysql_query` ... your choice.